# Как с помощью XPath достать текст

Tags: php, html, xpath

Есть путь к элементу

```
//div[@id='product_option_id']/text()
```

Получается такой результат: Product ID: 22826

HTML для него

```
<div class='item-last' id='product_option_id'>Product ID: 22826</div>
```

Как с помощью XPath получить только 22826 без "Product ID:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью XPath никак, текст надо разбить или заменить 'Product ID:':

```
echo end(explode(': ', $text));
```

или

```
echo str_replace('Product ID: ', '', $text);
```

Comment: а может с помощью каких-нибудь text()[1] или last(), я просто не знаю как их правильно применить:(

Comment: Тут по аналогии со всеми `DOM` парсерами - содержание элемента это один `string` и дальше работать с ним уже надо вручную. В вашем случае text() вернёт текстовую переменную.

Comment: понятно, спасибо!